# Is there a way to use string formatting inside a doc attribute in a macro?

Tags: rust, macros, documentation

I am using a macro to generate a series of enum variants. I would like to add a bit of documentation to each one, which I can do with the `#[doc = "..."]` attribute. This works fine if there's a string literal, but each macro variant has some additional data that I would like to put into the doc string.

In ordinary code, I would use `format!` to produce a formatted string. Is there any way to do this in a macro?

Here's a minimum example. It tries to generate a three-variant enum with a doc attribute on each variant. If the `format!` macro is replaced with a string literal, this works just fine.

```rust
macro_rules! fancy_enum {
    ($($name:ident => ($str:expr, $int:expr)),+) => {
        pub enum Fancy {
            $(
            #[doc = format!("Variant with string {} and value {}", $str, $int)]
            $name
            ),+
        }
    }
}

fancy_enum!(
    A => ("alpha", 1),
    B => ("bravo", 2),
    C => ("charlie", 3)
);
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: It's probably doable with procedural macros, but almost definitely not with only declarative macros.

Comment: Yeah, looking at the top-listed duplicate we're waiting on https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1628.

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e639640b3ca87edf4006f9ed76b34d4a).